# What does XHR return in case of absence of connection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Let's say I started google chrome. The extension also starts. It uses the XmlHttpRequest object.
But after I started browser, I noticed there's no connection to internet.
What does XHR return in case of absence of connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHR's onreadystatechange finally returns status "0" instead of "200", "404" or something else. So you slould check "readyState" property (it equals 4 in the end) and "status" property ("0" if no internet connection).

Btw, there's also navigator.onLine property which can help you to check the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

An `XMLHttpRequestException` exception with code 101 (`NETWORK_ERR`) is thrown after calling `send()`.